# Computing the Manhattan Distance between two clusters of points.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, metric-spaces

We have two clusters of points:

```
c1: (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)
c2: (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9)
```

I know the Manhattan Distance formula is as follows:

$d(a,b) = \sum|b_i - a_i|$

I would like to compute the distance between the two clusters.
How do we apply this to our problem? What values do we get b and a from?

I am confused on how to come up with $b_i−a_i$. For example, is $b_i$ the x value of each point in c2, the y value, or a combination of the two?

Comment: What do you want to compute?

Comment: @par the manhattan distance between the two clusters.

Comment: You should ask yourself *why* you want to compute it to figure out *what* it is that you need to compute.

Comment: @par I know what it is I need to compute. I am confused on how to come up with $b_i - a_i$. Is $b_i$ the x value of each point in c2, the y value, or a combination of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your points seem to be two-dimensional, the distance formula is as simple as :

$d(a, b) = |b_0 - a_0| + |b_1 - a_1|$

where a and b are the two-dimensional vectors. To be clear, $a_0$ and $b_0$ is 'x' and $a_1$ and $b_1$ are 'y', so :

d([2, 3], [5, 6]) = |5 - 2| + |6 - 3| = 3 + 3 = 6

To get the distance between clusters, you will have to pick a clustering technique, which is different from the *metric* (Euclidian, Manhattan, etc).

Comment: So for example: | [2 7] - [1 1] | + |[2 8 ] - [1 2]|

Comment: No. d([2, 7], [1, 3]) = |1 - 2| + |3 - 7|.